# What is this bird species in the Pacific NW?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I don’t think it’s a Black Phoebe, as they have black beaks not white. Is it a Grosbeak? This was taken in the Pacific NW.[image]. [image]. Sorry for the pic quality.

If this isn’t the right place to post this, please tell me where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [Dark-eyed Junco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark-eyed_junco), *Junco hyemalis*.  This one is a member of the "Oregon" subspecies, *J. h. oreganus*, which used to be considered a species, *Junco oreganus*, before a number of species were combined because they are capable of interbreeding.  The are small, ground-feeding birds, primarily consuming seeds and insects. There are two white outer tail feathers which are prominent when they are flying.

[image: Oregon dark-eyed junco] *(image: Andy Reago & Chrissy McClarren via [Wikipedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dark-eyed_Junco_(Oregon)_(14557821416).jpg))*

Comment: Thank you! That’s what it is. I have an app, Merlin Bird ID, that lists birds in the pac nw (or anywhere in the world actually), but the first pic didn’t look like it at all. Which is why I missed it. But as I went in and looked at all the pics the exact bird was there.